# Mule Internationalization Support (Japanese)

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have requirement as below.

My Mule flow as to read the properties file (src/main/resources) where this property file contains the Japanese characters in Value place.When mule flow trying to read the property files all the values are printing in ???? mode. I have written custom java component with  property file loading concept.Currently we are using mule 3.4 EE run time.

I have a question whether Mule 3.4 supports Internalization especially for Japanese characters.

What will be the best way to implement this scenario.

Regards
Vikram

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use [Resource Bundle Plugin](http://essiembre.github.io/eclipse-rbe/) which provides an editor for properties to be internationalized

Answer (score -1):

Vikram ,
I tried using '@' in MuleProperties file , Mule gave an error . I had to replace @ with %40 . Now , since you have Jap characters you need to change the Unicode pattern.

Unicode ranges for hiragana and katakana are:

Hiragana: Unicode: 3040-309F
Katakana: Unicode: 30A0–30FF

Change the above code and use the ASCII code

Comment: Please, specify an example of how to implement the scenario. The answer is not complete.